# Single Number solving by Haspmap, return always be a "@"

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

This is a question from leetcode. [Leetcode - Single Number I](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number/).

- ***Sinlge Number:*** ***Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.***
  **Input: [2,2,1]
  Output: 1**

I would like to use hashmap to solve it, but there is a mistake that my return key always be "@".

Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
public int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    char[] y = ("" + nums).toCharArray();
    int size=y.length;

    Map<Character,Integer>map=new HashMap<>();
    int i =0;
    while(i!=size) {
        if(map.containsKey(y[i])==false) {
            map.put(y[i],1);
        }
        else {
            int oldval=map.get(y[i]);
            int newval=oldval+1;
            map.put(y[i],newval);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    Set<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>>hmp=map.entrySet();
    for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer>data:hmp) {
        if(data.getValue()==1){
           return data.getKey();
        }
    }
     return 0;
}
}
```

I don't know what is the wrong. ( maybe the getkey() part?)

I appearite all your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] y = ("" + nums).toCharArray();
```

will not covert your `int` array to a `char` array.

`"" + nums` will produce a `String` that looks like "[I@33909752", so calling `toCharArray()` on that `String` will produce a `char` array that contains the character '@', which is why you are getting that character as the output (it happens to be the first non-repeating character in your `HashMap`).

Anyway, there is no need for you to try to convert the input `int` array to a `char` array.

Just use a `Map<Integer,Integer>` and work with the `nums` array directly.

This code will work:

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : nums) {
        if(!map.containsKey(i)) {
            map.put(i,1);
        } else {
            int oldval=map.get(i);
            int newval=oldval+1;
            map.put(i,newval);
        }
    }

    Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>hmp=map.entrySet();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>data:hmp) {
        if(data.getValue()==1){
           return data.getKey();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that this would be identified very quickly by stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: Also, the for loop can be much neater using `map.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);`.

Answer (score 2):

Do it using bitwise xor:

```
int result = 0;
for (int n : nums) {
  result ^= n;
}
return result;
```

This works because:

- `a ^ 0 = a`,
- `a ^ a = 0`
- `a ^ b = b ^ a`
- `(a ^ b) ^ c = a ^ (b ^ c)`

so paired numbers cancel each other out, wherever they appear in the array.

---

Note that whilst this is a very different approach to your answer, you can apply a similar approach to using a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int n : nums) {
  if (!map.remove(n)) {
    map.add(n, n);
  }
}
```

This adds and removes pairs of items from the map; at the end, there should only be 1 unpaired value left in the map.

```
return map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

(There's actually no reason to use a `Map` here, you may as well use a `Set`).

Comment: since the OP asking for help using hashmap, direct posting the answer is irrelavant i guess. SO is not for direct question-answer.

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative**".